# Confused on how to draw a flowchart for an if statement with AND operator

Tags: if-statement, flowchart

I understand how you make a flowchart for a simple if statement with a returning variable. However, adding an AND statement confuses me.

```
when a =>
    if   (x = "00") then 
            return upd;
end
```

but something like this confuses me on how to draw it:

```
when a =>

if(q= "0000" and w= "0000" and e= "0000" and r= "0000") then

return lftd;

end
```

I'm not sure if you need to put all of the AND statments within one diamond or if you need multiple diamonds for each AND.

I was hoping someone could maybe give a little more explanation on how to do this or provide me with some resourse on this particular thing. Would appreciate the help!